# google sheet - propagate a MAXIF function whitin a column

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table in a first sheet called 'Ansewers to form' with :

| Date | Name | First_Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 18/01/2023 14:44:18 | Name1 | FName1 |
| 18/01/2023 14:46:24 | Name1 | FName1 |
| 18/01/2023 16:37:30 | Name2 | FName2 |
| 18/01/2023 16:47:12 | Name1 | FName1 |
| 18/01/2023 16:47:35 | Name3 | FName3 |

And a second table called 'sheet1':

| Date | Name | First_Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 18/01/2023 16:47:12 | Name1 | FName1 |
| _ | Name2 | FName2 |
| _ | Name3 | Fname3 |

I would like to recover the latest connection of each Name/Fname.

So I the cell `A2` of sheet1 I have this formula :

```
=MAXIFS('Answers to form'!A2:A;'Answers to form'!B2:B;B2;'Answers to form'!C2:C;C2)
```

I would like to propagate the formula (just like with arrayformula); meaning that in `A3` you have
`=MAXIFS('Answers to form'!A2:A;'Answers to form'!B2:B;B3;'Answers to form'!C2:C;C3)`, and so...

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

In Google Sheets you might lock a column or row with `$`.
In your case

```
=MAXIFS('Answers to form'!$A$2:$A;'Answers to form'!$B$2:$B;$B2;'Answers to form'!$C$2:$C;$C2)
```

Will drag on second line (which is line 3) to

```
=MAXIFS('Answers to form'!$A$2:$A;'Answers to form'!$B$2:$B;$B3;'Answers to form'!$C$2:$C;$C3)
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, but how to do that automatically? I tried with arrayformula function but it did not work...